# Is it permissible to offer Salah if you have nail polish on?

Tags: practical-islam

I wanted to know that if it is allowed to offer Salah while having your nail color on. My question is specific to the permissibility of performing wudu while having nail color on.

Comment: Is the question about salah or about wudu'? For example, are you asking if a woman performs wudu', puts on nail polish, then performs salah, then takes off the nail polish before the next wudu'? Is this nail polish to be displayed only to mahrams? Or will it be to non-mahrams, too?

Comment: Is it permissible to perform wudu while having nail color on ?

Comment: Is the question *Is wudu valid if it's made while nail polish is worn?*  (Note that there are "halal" water-permeable nail polishes.)

Answer (score 2):

The rule is that water must reach and flow over an organ for it to be considered cleansed, either through *wudū'* (ablution) or *ghusl* (washing). To get the organ to be moist only is not enough; water must be able to flow. [Imam An-Nawawi](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Al-Nawawi) in his book *Al-Majmū'* said:

> <sub>**NOTE.** My own translation, so treat with care.</sub>
>
> الوضوء هو جريان الماء على الأعضاء ودليله أنه لا يسمى غسلا ما لم يجر ولو غمس عضوه في الماء كفاه لأنه يسمى غسلا
>
> Ablution is the flow of water on the organs, and its evidence is that it is not called washing if there is no flow. If the organ is immersed
>   in water, it suffices as this is called washing.
>
> إذا كان على بعض أعضائه شمع أو عجين أو حناء واشتباه ذلك فمنع وصول الماء الى شئ من العضو لم تصح طهارته سواء كثر ذلك أم قل ولو بقي على اليد وغيرها أثر الحناء ولونه دون عينه أو أثر دهن مائع بحيث يمس الماء بشرة العضو ويجري عليها لكن لا يثبت صحت طهارته
>
> If some of the organs have wax, dough, or *henna*, and there is a doubt that [such material] prevented water from reaching a portion of the organ, whether it is much or little, this renders the ablution not valid. Even if what remains on the hand or other organs is a trace of the *henna* or its color or a trace of paint that prevents the water from touching the skin [or surface] of the organ and flow on it, the ablution is invalid.
>
> <sub>— [Al-Majmū', Vol. 2, pp. 467-468](https://al-maktaba.org/book/2186/469#p2)</sub>

This is based on a number of hadiths on the subject, one of which is that of a companion having one spot on his foot that was not washed, and the Prophet ﷺ commanded him to redo his ablution:

> حَدَّثَنَا حَيْوَةُ بْنُ شُرَيْحٍ، حَدَّثَنَا بَقِيَّةُ، عَنْ بَحِيرٍ، - هُوَ ابْنُ سَعْدٍ - عَنْ خَالِدٍ، عَنْ بَعْضِ، أَصْحَابِ النَّبِيِّ أَنَّ النَّبِيَّ صلى الله عليه وسلم رَأَى رَجُلاً يُصَلِّي وَفِي ظَهْرِ قَدَمِهِ لُمْعَةٌ قَدْرُ الدِّرْهَمِ لَمْ يُصِبْهَا الْمَاءُ فَأَمَرَهُ النَّبِيُّ صلى الله عليه وسلم أَنْ يُعِيدَ الْوُضُوءَ وَالصَّلاَةَ
>
> Narrated Some Companions of the Prophet: The Prophet (ﷺ) saw a person offering prayer, and on the back of his foot a small part equal to the space of a dirham remained unwashed; the water did not reach it. The Prophet (ﷺ) commanded him to repeat the ablution and prayer.
>
> <sub>— [Sunan Abi Dawud, Book 1, Hadith 175](https://www.sunnah.com/abudawud/1/175)</sub>

The nail polish used, regardless of its brand, type, color, etc., if it forms a layer that isolates the organ below from having water flow on it, then it renders the *wudū'* invalid. If, however, the nail polish is applied to the toes when in a state of valid ablution then covered by socks, it is permissible to wipe on top of the socks for the period allowed as the feet will have been clean at the time of wearing the socks:

> عن عروة بن المغيرة، عن أبيه، أنه وضأ النبي صلى الله عليه وسلم فتوضأ ومسح على خفيه فقال له فقال: إِنِّي أَدْخَلْتُهُمَا طَاهِرَتَيْنِ
>
> 'Urwah al Mughira reported it from his father: He (Mughira) helped the Apostle (ﷺ) in performing the ablution, and he performed it and wiped over his shoes. He (Mughira) said to him (about the washing of the feet after putting them off), but he (the Holy Prophet) said: "I put them (feet) in when these were clean."
>
> <sub>— [Sahih Muslim, Book 2, Hadith 99](https://sunnah.com/muslim/2/99)</sub>

Praying with nail polish on is permissible as there is no textual or traditional evidence to the contrary. You may refer to Islam Q&A's articles on [the effect of permeable nail polish on the validity of wudoo’](https://islamqa.info/en/202971) and [praying with nail polish](https://islamqa.info/en/20728) for more information.